# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined(…)

Tags: angularjs, scope, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image from my html an on click of save button, i am calling an upload function in the controller. When i enter the upload function in controller, i am not able to access $scope to check the $scope.file.name.

```
//upload image.html    
<div class="horizontal">
<table border=1 frame=void rules=rows class="ui celled table" >
<thead style="text-align: center;">
  <tr>
    <th> Id </th>
    <th> Question </th>
    <th> Option A </th>
    <th> Option B </th>
    <th> Option C </th>
    <th> Option D </th>
    <th> Answer </th>
    <th> Section id </th>
    <th> Image </th>
    <th> Edit</th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="ques in questionObj | filter: searchText" style="text-align: center;">
    <tr>
      <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
      <td><span ng-show="editEnabled" ng-model="Title">
        {{ ques.Title || 'empty' }}
      </span>
      <div ng-hide="editEnabled">
        <textarea ng-model="ques.Title"></textarea>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><span ng-show="editEnabled" ng-model="Title">{{ques.Option_a || 'empty'}} </span> 
      <div ng-hide="editEnabled" class="option">
        <textarea ng-model="ques.Option_a"></textarea>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><span ng-show="editEnabled" ng-model="Title">{{ques.Option_b || 'empty'}} </span>
      <div ng-hide="editEnabled" class="option">
        <textarea ng-model="ques.Option_b"></textarea>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><span ng-show="editEnabled" ng-model="Title">{{ques.Option_c || 'empty'}} </span>
      <div ng-hide="editEnabled" class="option">
        <textarea ng-model="ques.Option_c"></textarea>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><span ng-show="editEnabled" ng-model="Title">{{ques.Option_d || 'empty'}} </span>
      <div ng-hide="editEnabled" class="option">
        <textarea ng-model="ques.Option_d"></textarea>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><span ng-show="editEnabled" ng-model="Title">{{ques.Answer || 'empty'}} </span>
      <div ng-hide="editEnabled" class="option">
        <textarea ng-model="ques.Answer"></textarea>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td><span ng-show="editEnabled" ng-model="Title">{{ques.Section_id || 'empty'}} </span>
      <div ng-hide="editEnabled" class="option">
        <input type="text" ng-model="ques.Section_id"></input>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span ng-if="ques.Image != 'nil'" ng-show="editEnabled" ng-model="Title"> <img ng-src="{{ques.Image}}" class="image-container" /></span>
      <span ng-if="ques.Image === 'nil'" ng-show="editEnabled" ng-model="Title">No Image</span>

      <div ng-if="ques.Image != 'nil'" ng-hide="editEnabled" class="option">
        <img ng-src="{{ques.Image}} " class="image-container" />
      </div>

      <div ng-if="ques.Image === 'nil'" ng-hide="editEnabled" class="option">
        <input class="bottom-marg-15" type="file" name="file" file onchange="angular.element(this).scope().imageLoad(this)"></input>
        <!-- Progress Bar -->
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ uploadProgress }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{ uploadProgress }}%;">
            {{ uploadProgress == 0 ? '' : uploadProgress + '%' }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="step in stepsModel">
        <img class="small-thumb" ng-src="{{step}}" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td style="white-space: nowrap">
      <div class="buttons" ng-show="editEnabled" ng-show="editEnabled">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="editEnabled = !editEnabled">edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="question.removeUser($index,ques.Id)">del</button>
      </div> 
      <div ng-hide="editEnabled" class="form-buttons form-inline">
        <button ng-model="Title" ng-disabled="editQuestionForm.$waiting" ng-click=" upload(); editEnabled = !editEnabled" class="btn btn-primary">
          save
        </button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="editEnabled = !editEnabled" class="btn btn-default">
          cancel
        </button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

this is the controller which has the upload function. I am not able to access $scope inside upload function.

```
    'use strict';
angular.module('onlineTestAngularApp')
.controller('editQuestionCtrl', function($scope, GetQuestionsService, $window, $location, localStorageService, ENV) {
var vm = this;
vm.success = false;
vm.auth_token = localStorageService.get('rec-auth-token');
vm.role = localStorageService.get('role');
$scope.editEnabled = true;
$scope.access_key = ENV.access_key;
$scope.secret_key = ENV.secret_key;
$scope.bucket = "q-auth/angular_test/";

$scope.stepsModel = [];

$scope.imageLoad = function(element){
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = $scope.imageIsLoaded;
 reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
}

$scope.imageIsLoaded = function(e){
 $scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.stepsModel.push(e.target.result);
 });
}

$scope.upload = function($scope){
 console.log("inside upload");
}
});
```

Comment: Can you please create plunker or fiddle for it?

Answer (score 0):

Once you enter the controller's function you have access to its `$scope`. There's no need to pass it as a parameter:

**Controller**

```
$scope.upload = function() {
console.log($scope.stepsModel) // or any other property
}
```

It seems you mix two techniques for accessing controller's scope: `vm` and `$scope`. My advice is to use `vm` only for exposing the controller variables to the view. Using `$scope` will soon be deprecated and I use it mainly for `$watch`ing changes in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Your upload() is having a parameter called $scope, remove it.

Change:

```
$scope.upload = function($scope){
 console.log("inside upload");
}
```

To:

```
$scope.upload = function(){
 console.log("inside upload");
};
```

Because when you call the function upload() it will expect to pass an argument, $scope in the function is taken as local variable of that function, hence becoming undefined.